# Sum of Dataframe Column and use it on Ifelse condition

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, sum

I am trying to find out whether the sum of a `pd.DataFrame` column is larger than some value, `b`. However, I keep getting an error.

This is my code:

```
    import pandas as pd 
      
    # initialize data of lists. 
    data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 
      
    # Create DataFrame 
    df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
    
    a = df['Age'].sum()
    b = 50
    if b > a:
        print("b is greater than a")
    elif a == b:
        print("a and b are equal")
```

This is the error message:

```
"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
```

Comment: What's the `dtype` of `Age`?

Comment: It is working for me when I run it. Are you sure this code block is where the error comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its Working properly for mi **can you specify the line at witch you are getting the error**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the mistakes I got two columns of Age that is why I got the error.